# Powershell - How to search for Whole Words (or) Exact Matches

Tags: regex, powershell

this is my requirement.

I need to find if a certain CSS classes is referenced in my Solution which has over 120 aspx pages.

This is the command that we wrote

```
gci . -include *.aspx -recurse | select-string -pattern ".rtop" -caseSensitive >> D:\CSSResult.txt
```

However, this matches even words with rtop in middle. That is, if I have a variable named as dirtopy, it comes in the result list. I do not want that.

I want it in the result only if an exact match of .rtop is found.

How do I do it?

Any references or examples would be more than sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `select-string -pattern "\.rtop\b"`.

You need to escape the dot, or it will match any character; and the `\b` word boundary anchor ensures that the word does not continue after `rtop`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But, this also returns a string occurrence of rtop*                                                  Any particular reason why it does so?

Comment: You mean an asterisk after rtop? Yes, this regex allows that; it just checks for word boundaries, and there is one between a letter and a non-alphanumeric character like `*`. What do you want to allow after `rtop` - whitespace or end-of-string? In that case, replace the `\b` with `(?=\s|$)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the -simplematch option of select-string to do a literal match instead of regex.

Comment: Thanks! But, if I have a file which has the following .rtop, .rtop1, .rtop* and dirtopy then using a simplematch option returns all occurrences of .rtop, .rtop1 and .rtop* (it excludes only dirtopy). So, does that mean that it returns all string occurrences where the first set of characters is rtop? But that is in direct contradiction to what MSDN says "If this parameter is specified, the cmdlet performs a simple match rather than a regular expression match." No?

Comment: It means it will return all the lines that contain the literal string ".rtop". The difference is how the dot gets treated. Unsing -simplematch, it must match a dot. Using regex it will match any single character in that position, since a dot in a regex means "any character".  You can exclude anything with characters following ".rtop" by doing a simple match on ".rtop " (add a space to the end to further qualify the match).